# Access shared folder from linux machine using java code

Tags: java, linux, samba

I'm getting an error with the following coge.
It cannot convert smbfile to file. How to copy my file to windows shared folder?

```
SmbFile fromfile = new SmbFile("smb://192.168.10.117/TempLibrary/");
FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory((File) filelist.get(i), fromfile);
```

Comment: `SmbFile` does not extend `File`. There is no [tag:rmi] here. Don't tag indiscriminately.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot cast `SmbFile` to `File` but you can use `SmbFile.getInputStream()` and `SmbFile.getOutputStream()` to access the file's actual data and then use `FileUtils.copyFile(File,OutputStream)`, `FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(InputStream, File)` or similar.